How to Join Two Unequal-Length Columns by Matching Identical Strings
I have two tibbles with unique values, with unequal length like:
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "T", "C", "D", "X", "F")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

> df1
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  col1 
  <chr>
1 A    
2 T    
3 C    
4 D    
5 X    
6 F 

> df2
# A tibble: 9 × 1
  col2 
  <chr>
1 A    
2 B    
3 C    
4 D    
5 F    
6 G    
7 H    
8 I    
9 J   

I would like to get:
> df3
# A tibble: 11 × 2
   col1  col2 
   <chr> <chr>
 1 A     A    
 2 NA    B    
 3 T     NA   
 4 C     C    
 5 D     D    
 6 X     NA   
 7 F     F    
 8 NA    G    
 9 NA    H    
10 NA    I    
11 NA    J

Each identical string in col1 of df1 and col2 in df2 should be in the same row side by side. For example, if a string in col1 and col2 is the same, they should be in the same row (e.g., string A).
If a string exists in col1 but not in col2, it should be NA in col2, and vice versa.
I would be grateful for any further advice.

Does the row order matter?

library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = join_by(col1 == col2), keep = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 2
#>    col1  col2 
#>    <chr> <chr>
#>  1 A     A    
#>  2 T     <NA> 
#>  3 C     C    
#>  4 D     D    
#>  5 X     <NA> 
#>  6 F     F    
#>  7 <NA>  B    
#>  8 <NA>  E    
#>  9 <NA>  G    
#> 10 <NA>  H    
#> 11 <NA>  I    
#> 12 <NA>  J


Perfect. Many thanks. I just forgot the keep argument!

A base R solution
lst <- c(df1, df2)
v <- unique(unlist(lst))
list2DF(lapply(lst, \(x) x[match(v, x)]))

gives
   col1 col2
1     A    A
2     T <NA>
3     C    C
4     D    D
5     X <NA>
6     F    F
7  <NA>    B
8  <NA>    E
9  <NA>    G
10 <NA>    H
11 <NA>    I
12 <NA>    J


Another base R solution is using stack + reshape
reshape(
  transform(
    stack(c(df1, df2)),
    r = as.integer(factor(values))
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "r",
  timevar = "ind"
)[-1]

which gives
   values.col1 values.col2
1            A           A
2            T        <NA>
3            C           C
4            D           D
5            X        <NA>
6            F           F
8         <NA>           B
11        <NA>           E
13        <NA>           G
14        <NA>           H
15        <NA>           I
16        <NA>           J


The third base R option is using table
d <- table(stack(c(df1, df2)))
as.data.frame(ifelse(d > 0, row.names(d), NA))

which gives
  col1 col2
A    A    A
B <NA>    B
C    C    C
D    D    D
E <NA>    E
F    F    F
G <NA>    G
H <NA>    H
I <NA>    I
J <NA>    J
T    T <NA>
X    X <NA>

Benchmark
tic1 <- \() {
  lst <- c(df1, df2)
  v <- unique(unlist(lst))
  list2DF(lapply(lst, \(x) x[match(v, x)]))
}

tic2 <- \() {
  reshape(
    transform(
      stack(c(df1, df2)),
      r = as.integer(factor(values))
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "r",
    timevar = "ind"
  )[-1]
}

tic3 <- \() {
  d <- table(stack(c(df1, df2)))
  as.data.frame(ifelse(d > 0, row.names(d), NA))
}

microbenchmark(
  tic1(),
  tic2(),
  tic3(),
  unit = "relative"
)

shows
Unit: relative
   expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 tic1()  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000 1.000000   100
 tic2() 40.30049 30.210059 16.153643 30.60000 24.474138 1.423185   100
 tic3() 13.77833  9.902367  6.136188 10.15569  9.180251 1.553357   100


A base solution using merge, by adding a new column to use for merging and removing it afterwards.
merge(cbind(x=df1[[1]], df1), cbind(x=df2[[1]], df2), all=TRUE)[-1]
#   col1 col2
#1     A    A
#2  <NA>    B
#3     C    C
#4     D    D
#5  <NA>    E
#6     F    F
#7  <NA>    G
#8  <NA>    H
#9  <NA>    I
#10 <NA>    J
#11    T <NA>
#12    X <NA>

